# EF7 migrations no longer working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using Entity Framework 7 RC1 on an ASP.NET 5 RC1 app. It's been going allright for a while, but all of a sudden

```
dnx ef migrations add <name>
```

no longer works.

The feedback I get is "Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'", but nothing happens, no file is added or altered. I have tried to delete my database, and also to delete all the migrations and start from scratch but 'ef migrations add' does absolutely nothing. It works when I try on a fresh project.

What to do?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you have some problem/inconsistency in your model, that the RC1 tooling just can't handle. Maybe check/undo your latest changes to your model and retry?

Comment: Thanks, but it was something else - don't know what. I solved it by deleting the repo and cloning a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was causing the issue, but deleting the solution and cloning a fresh copy from Github solved the problem.